# How is the font centered vertically?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I use the font `Merel`

Example with the usual Arial font (everything works fine)

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #00f;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block-inner {
  background: #f00;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-inner">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Example with `Merel` font (not centered)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merel';
  src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff2');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<style>
  .block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #00f;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .block-inner {
    background: #f00;
    font-family: 'Merel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
</style>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-inner">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to center this font vertically?
I will be glad to any help. Thank you

Comment: did you try `vertical-align:middle` It works i guess

Comment: alas it does not work. Example https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/j7hg54kz/

Comment: a weird font ... a lot of space on the top. It's seems strange but it's actually centred

Comment: Because that's not the way fonts work....they have different spacing above and below the actual *glyph* [for ascenders and descenders] and `leading` and **every single one is different.**

Comment: @ Paulie_D I understand it. And then how to vertically center this font?

Comment: You can't....it's not *designed* to be centered.

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now is to add `padding-bottom` on your element and to reduce your `line-height`... It will not be *really* centered, but will looks *visually* centered.

Comment: Line-height will do nothing....you can reduce it to 0 and the text won't move and the amount of bottom padding will be a *fudge* at best or ineffective at worst.

Comment: @Paulie_D I agree that it is not a solution, though it can do the trick depending on what OP really need.

Comment: But it's completelty inflexible...change the font and the whole thing breaks. if pin point accuracy is required use negative margin/a transform/positioning or JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *approximate* it like this but keep in mind that the font was already **centred** because it was designed like that, so this is a hack to have the needed visual.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merel';
  src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABAAAAAEakAA8AAAAA+fgAAEZEAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP0ZGVE0cGiobyWYcjA4GYACHbhEICoLYIIH+SguHNgABNgIkA45oBCAFizMHl3EbX8gn0Nv2CHE7gPS/W+5YIt52BHerTIAALDIQbBx4wNpjZf//f0bSMYZj5hBVk3qHqGRcxpsTudyE0Jqjx4iuTuRw26ebhe3N3DdOlESF280yd65nvG2hXxbl4nOVTtWjDvcR+MWCsLEn7clFRYXNVPBMUdlj3qel3LSgU9RVXyLtoN+5JG/+6mCULARTddnNkkkVD1U5v0uypjz0TwWvZBUYu8xGRKwTVS8FtPaf1bPvHzCoC1ggVACgolAhSAIdlbgTKkTCsQL+gd9m7xOKlEWJggiijdmIjQqY083GbMTtrAVuN13bW9/NmgvEpUsXqau8W7uqu5UD58RX2QGPdPJFx6OTDnwqYkmb3g+R6MlGpyA8RkUrMYryOIeEgwQvAStYwIr/AJEJvkT2Jb+nvqnvrmS/trtSUYYAGkJohdB6RAsnn52zouSd0yuw2/HPXfJ3l/ZLsgxBGTAskywH1SoEe7fOIycF/CUwa83HTY6V7dTYOtbP3ACw0UVmr/z8vHwcx3G8HMfx8PDISfLxPzhv8ZWccLrmD57bHiQHlRtUNyKM7SMNRKbmFhuhzkR/qgehZMxMtWQkwZsFQUIwXGUzvfzvdfkfANCA/tQAIdINHQRYlinZ/7sWkC2AVPs/m2k7K+me5QtxZ3d2F3r9nQNUdGnTNLN/Vrs7s7unWfBJ3j3AZ51kWEkGmQVnRyeTdAYOVsAV0GUvBFRRT9TlpeOiTarUbdKmS5uiq1KH/fqxVu+Bx7PpG3b6hUYkRtiPvVvMFtEk5iETIqmLJg+Fe6df0u/1XWozTOuAX6f3Fh9gAehH0o5cv1JaQbVoNCOvPbZTSuEBtEAYQjs8gFIJ8AYtgPHh7917p7WOHUzDB9ZSGmvzA6yofeuPabLEAsIPBJ+Hz9v59nBUGnnq3f3JslmYYBcEmHPCoQz+P/c2+7YBkRTXFU4gFXNukp1NKKWo0oViH1/RrEd5jOSvtd5sWAGWj5KpqFSkmgWeWaD+Aebdgfy33b2p3n6vO8B0wCzsCYOaQKhzZ57IvyS2g9X7/dlEVVTU6W1Y1lG6tn+WEGRPwiJBrBXrDXOzIhJ66ftuw9kl2KATErSmL7qMTeMRhfZh5EAwpjG1s+mvzB9pd4bKVFEcOEFA4atmLUfHBbfs7AHTNylo+SEhwBdvRhwAH1+Q/a9/rCPAEmAXMKAh+Ybkxy90/m6HwAADCFgk10roUz6J44FynaKyGMxvz6wuBVcYwP9zaCCosd8E5uS38RyZcW6s+N7notjofS6RRZW6BKOv+1pVDpTb5JWlwLyKCEhcIgREGym+MBh4BtgsIEDMoYCpjIvCRyaAAdrx8/T3nN+AwMPCwkP0MmcHQhkXUmnTtF0/jNO8rNt+nNf9AyAEIyiGEyRFMyzHC6IkK6pumJbtuOfr/SnKqm7arh/GaV7WbT/O637e7//x89f/vv800/8BgWa4PJbtcHgCkUQqV6ohBCMoRqs3erw+CBQGRyBRaAwWhycQSWQKlUZnMFlsDpfHFwiF0gRHokPmcsMAFxg0Ztwhxz3yzOtQiCNvydLkq9Wox9TPLW/d2oJ1uFEbPqW3xpvr86CNs9x1Ld525/0320g0Ay1D92GYGEeMECPGpGByMA2oLkwbph2zFtOD2YYZxUxgZjCvMd+xOKwN1hPVhRViw7EybHJIuU/njerxR2JY5A0BBCOrnS71RagUDXQwwCQiWFAjjrKQSnXRJmhyr1fpHuJmT0FJWc6FQG6cjFTGBzRxojaVazHR13Aq4UbRSByBakAwHuhEFMMdskAaa9Se9O1GtiXaathmVo5LYJIlSc4GuJUK7UTC8GdS3BNxm79yPBNdkgUYCsvBcDA4b/WQBjYm44pahbVZaupjel6/QCgZ0/wcVPrz5bFLEqWSl5dSRQAd+4wBI6eJnUfg+cwbI4J6zMziiThj58FK0aBDz1E6ljwXYiGrj8Baopag54lxakXKAGCagr1jGp+1C9Hb7K4YIkEAsQsYTQRY5yZcCEBn09jawkaRSVR1c4hKMjmwSCyClVtELspH+dMugzzbwlva1AEm7lUQ+EIj7zNGLiwv42N48d34U5kOEcBKSZpVcxAgL2hwqIwfQ9NTRPHLngspPdcAbKrx1hfh6oETg1k29o6Dp/LyzHckLEZt+HQ0MRKGjK6eCEe5uIp1D8Gp6FBSFlp9Ydc0mbBjWJTbskiIZX79+aincV7fvkyhx5qs5pS2wUWlJcc98RVKlr6PvYOUziZC8uraPLvCUfV2ZXQbgAPnu8SAxCQICiHBEwlA9raSBTVFEjOQpPSKSFaIIo5xpewiJDUG31EGDxEVjREmYya4rLlw49GQtJTGQtpCrCF4NPRWUO1S8WE1Gz0zQpRosTW+mVfZf1wZMmXJlkMuV4EiJcpUqFSlWg0FpUYLNcHgCCQKHWrNT8CAZWc8oAGPKyDEEg1rux3rVGgVyY4rxky1jRAZQpAj2N7sXKpXT+jo/yf/utnSg5PedhtbUa4GO84BtdYmH0B4JZVbu4KfOEFIrOvWp+eHlHEFD8GNflWgk9cnSuqT4mGrHZYoBkqkPZFJq0AwtmabEIO39DooMTvs5l4LTg2x8ooAYzto23XGyfpUtlXCVZGihtaSuV+qKKWUqaZeQptaq6/SY/bU3Gg4B6eWa5EVCZxgkqamyH7WwxzPAtrWn+b2OTgV0y+dk9NdGMBRPIJJ8+UxVoYoMK16tl8qWCvYalMbtOKZEloVjsbnBok1ZGMqyf35cOXjhlvLsZZKQPEghiiwNTTBgofsovjxepznIBsMMxJzBlUKNVoQGdUi2xRmATQno8HiQp9/TrjO6PkvOiVaX2SoWFv8Sftzqg+8LsAIzRV0jknNo1PBZsdKorDQLNsUJc5qvtcVDm41nPUuApo70eSu0RsU3TQgjAj2IjfYd/tF1bg4HiPm5UQ9eRu9UzciHv75WMgQYBEzhrQYIwHr6DClDxPg1lVQ8g+kXSjAFoD1wA4GsJgALACWQ2Mg6Lpr9z8cbJPJCrcIKlCpW1cyS9MT53OBXUdCtgq2ApE6eTFmRmWQscHOFevZlREB4AKQzL/iW9GRwXpWnYqHVeESLYBdN2dL4YLdUxdC00egDUS1NnCKlBDwPwhUPqqHvJ6I0G04JqJTnX1VvjtXpsueuocDsBHx33MneyYYDOkgsKLLBv6NDnZIMPQIaLNGRQH2M+YCYUuLKT4iOjQaHDzu3t62HbmjP7ce1heW1do0hrLRTRPB6SR6O6kXgqMh54PQb8azRYaFyvSRPB71V0BGpn0yOLj72soBhvbD7kdnBpDMnmlmgp8xENcbol+cgEYXPrPBVRkY5jeIE5Y24Oy6gzqofEA63epWHXGaHrnTp7mbRWUdxtgSjyD6md9ip1ZwWx1vdXhFQoSLECWGhJRMnCTzpEg1/3a8j9es/Ta7P2ePXn36Ddhoky222ma7IcNGjNplzB4aE/Y74KBDDjti8ja+y5930WXT1e1b97qP1cXf+eCTL8U3fNj/fshCBwUBXZIq6OgaqYQrWSjBdan2KgyOmQLv7eMJCoNu2dHX9d/2/wdWUfMWtTTbok/cAlP8cgosbFBLYcX1oYpFb9HeY2Hf2dGz+bpvnYrHpH9t0h50EZQkBsQroo6aqG5ChRShsMUqraQKVbzSLl1hKlDo2hWxFYrcn4pQhyUcFHvmJLAnkQdxvKjFmzp8qU1ERChJ4og3j1gpVowGTQg2WLX12ASxmSQTxDtAgoNEHCLBYSKOkGCSiGMkOUGSU1FSOAEuvAAXUYCLpnSiK0wMpR1TaWemCHEVkksvXNZjpCZROjUrTC1Kp1aFqU3ptFhhWtJLG5kaCpN70BB6CAwUqUkoRMTtKHa8dAVMRbz/n0oIEXeISERYRAYY2MwhMQPVGyiLQKEA5BcQbCISUjnKQyD5hQDzIOqBprQdCZlyIko0ap8DjppywYxbHnhi1ntf/QyF4BAyQsHEYcGOM0/+RCJJJJovS75S1Ro0oYl0rljX2NLe1dsZl1xzxyPPvPax//o9MCg8Sm+0mYw7qwnmOu8FLnTiyZa8tOWscOWrXeNaxk6eOX/N9TfNFsxa3wAZzFCAIIOAyyu/0AkEZpOpXZaYdNzyD/9inMNQhBsPQh8WBgT6rF+mKJ8HBcaCYRcJA/D4vCbZKIBjoTcZgmGP6+ddFiBkPgkL163S8GmnnHLx7YHJohMcIMKmhmrb8WhOnGBnHrTqx0RHuFrxYsQikP59SRIkIWuymL7llqPbZDuGIUPYjjrF1Dkz+K65RuCGGxz86zlHs15x99Ynnr6HB/+ICAlic+KatP1OJZTal8CiTDy5hxMEnnAX7ncJiEjIdK3brnAnfgnhQOR9nyayk2WfCs8OSqlV3g8KDd3Vl0zUBu8N9Zg9QbKWGQItXTq3MaqB1ddaLgnau7ZUuAqCnalE/P1612QWV0PW9aVlJVB4Y2VmNpTfXpZdDA0DmrAEK7AaXRhY23ZnTUklDN59TWHsvkAb4/dVOTrBofu3zOP3MouFAApxV6BksgNwwAIDNLSgDTx0oQ+DoH/TQ2XHla9QMRKlyVWq1iJLrLTegL+NmXDUGVcgQIahgbJICxhd8x0CNGiKFW/+hEJFipEorWUFX0bhVvjbmIn2Mes+2cHnKTIUoanK7jbSqBH77LLHhL009lNX+MOJ89xwRLsdcIpKozOYLDaHG9h0GBCJZ77Xgw6bDAPxOemICeke8QVCkVgilcnDDhQC7vyRbYotYDu4GuzBwS3QeRRUiE9FS0DDSEjHSsTASczES8IiSMomSsYhLeRcsh3TDAPqoBg1oBk9YJhRwDTjP2ACBcWQCegj3/DQwEDBhOBAgNUQiFgIRJVp5tBziPCIQobBGGZmvJpa7xBaZfr+vNiMHwqlbCQ+2jMui92WZlAnJHJJHIE19n/fZbcCQdowWXrC8E65dLKf1n9XAJZSvOq/Y1zZgYvcbaN8BB5eyRBkOkR8A56d2t4egl3JxqNAYMxCqdo0vfJQHKjeWuv/r/nd/jSsdYYF47HVA2frvK7M2fv/WxWtRsyHF+7Ss5NigIOz9xyaetiPevoamRO8DOiZ8YEd0EBPEEYALceGjH9dMZ0J3CkQlsAiOw3bbZ+JEoghYzyWbLnwEC5aqjxFFrk3453e/ROLUwQTeyp9vJj9iUPhMDlsDpdjwXHkeHNEnGEzmhnXTGCWxkVxz7j3uA+5TC6ba8sN52Zw5fxzc2CHzYaM2mfcwdIIDZsFGwLuvESSSFOo1MUxNrVbsQS98ZrYHzmGHAbHhMPZa+nVlNpyIXMo/6OhuccCz03lsuOjmcsXzw8PDfb3dqdJ/HtMC4Hpv/x+OfwSPIZ/X3CNK13hcpc4x/Mdp9ePWlWvEgUxQB9rWM1yltFIBhGErv8ConPnDTygptVpEdSCTLi26VEcZwFHpynH7iumUVQ3HeMeYx/9LGymOMxw8e71fF/8BQgURCiYSIhQYcsqNBKeWPRcTV5eofGNJiKevMxyQwukSZchEyy1/HfearlO6/Xq0WdAv40222qLbbb7yw5/22nIiGGjxuyyz15q46mVyZYjv9VV6laisJ4qFLSzJqvrV96gSbmgV3W0g94JwKv2UMhS3PagdwO3qWlN4AELdfjuR8twJDKe0O6m7a9qA5fFDujZqlpBYdaojdJiLZZaRmWJP60EnrDWOms8zI1PpXnw5FV1vry5B/p/DgXo24Dpg2B6PTjqW4BTPgQAxwDMgUXTS4/AQkPW1SjlnwJqbBy6rb7qtEETRLwTta+IrgvBYVo+nYQooWIZA1BhglrVmXOCwRTwxPUSUtpHaBM0EIx4DBpUJ/iMW6kUvugatlOCIXYJEiJ9c7toMFtHPkFNDCWiFcaphDnvRBEdJaJDJvwGooNOkAV82gOPEjEGhAMWkiO1TfsGe+6iYHvoACQDAJ7EUGor75ozkBnaP0N3FKDIy/gLGTF2hZSSHkLBqIfXNvSNccuSMNA49gryjj/UoWK1B5otLj4jKqBwzHhVZ2QtFFKw0Ll37qbjwpym5iY3CdhNcq5/lnsfruUs5xvi5vFUbkT+tiSwxwmfoyJwOHRyA6i0wdw+WM7bER0YGeqcRFpCKodPND2lNbJBmHHPmPWKk2rC7QDjib69RYebk45a8Y6FjAx1TqJQsn8mfmI3ATJOggJ3ste1p0vhclIiLXHeW50pFR3EqSWh4uvDF7EngSG7eSCcZkdKk93ERuu7e5+smeVlQfEnQMwjbO9x7OL5gShm7ky+eY4WEFmCkAgH3HvCUWVQjQyrlsdrqVNO/gP6BMxGXSse6238eHS2xit+/v03YT+3X6a5bB7FJQu90EHY5uTTs4VB+ZSsKCQwZFPrYAtNiA0OZW4ppIvXxCJAsGojA17jJzSWMGOxSHYgyGZeDVSs4NJOr7XUOcIBKvZat0C2TUuDChTnxIyFx6Krtv7dtH/04ptss406Bd3bW/ZWKcLqAnYTx+lxtsi0BxW61Ra7g/0IQuhjFR1Bf/aw7tFZNLnEw61ZzsKVtanweJ0W6Tve3JwoxMfRqI6YUQkb1oREcvA9C9WO5tNUyg4nUUS3D+45CixOZZPn8PNyslFLWccDUepvCrI6H9eUTLgOSjrtPADmffshtDSSj0AZi/06Tp4JIbKt89tga1cZTryxGhKTWor6t0XcFAR0V0OPdXhlLnauQSvLRu8+9KAlOeyrAi5td0MessfNCTpy54E747imsD3ru02ZsDH2wjadlzkqARkqUPfqLXqhQlJBaMYO7xTI9qDFmRVQux9YNTl0P3gwynIdU9hR+WYNIUyXCuYd41JzjxKXktLymHnW+blFhOY2M5LdyVnXGsoKtTo+uxCBfASidAWGhVruPAGmWJoJP+MJhEPykRrc9Q6m3QTQeQaNesE0OfNz96g47h37jX3U0XihtkgwP2mVceySAJQSWleRPe6fMySxBpIe1uaJ+3RkY4MeUfSVYCO5LaG+RQQEgwGP64VaQrAWnNmkDwJ0j2/9k3rnHd0tAmtgP86KMadGkEnFuQU25uY24EZzU8YOa+hWH5yRgDQ2t2VTlmvnzCmM3CISbEhkkaTFni69OEvy8YiHt3bdxnxbJyZuSjzi0+/4J/6zGooiinNCg3OwA0+N7u+hGmsvb0xXcJaOZ+ywdeXd1FCqL+U7oZXFQzJ6K9LfJqLNQGLG6uH7glr7vj0LCrXALJq0iSow333yoCYpyqWm0b8Hm0KYNY4IxhCJuYZUMNOCTHTiEi+gATeYiBQx58QdnhTlAvgxOYkFbUqYroYvpI4KhHjZR1peOuiSQPEtBEKqBwTLXco4lNTXT783MF2qL4PPmAHfOdy5QMM8LcNnUuqNDq9sYvvI0C/1aMYO12V86phTI0gcFDQ3CFan5CMBQtFHo6psLhqxj1qdoVB72B+cIK/rSGstmCrYZKqjZ1xF6AGoMmoNwEhppgWxZa8NNsYaOxqYj2Y4Q5c4oFJPT2tfcQkyJQB5cb+kvqO/8D8AmMfVh9q0qn4z8ZZ6BYqHD8CVaGoyEk217m5SDizeE4BojqqkdzE9kC3Ah61ZzGMuPiBpg4gNI+oHi2oyMuY52hYPu/0W2parZJ1SdVwAOjL/+lBJOFvicR9FbWAAOytgr26jpL137iGwt30rqveAvRlMeIPsbfrbceqx+UT3nzGKWEKpGYWOeNtN6Y5749KZ8sDJB5iODKHchTht2GDK9/sE80888F/elnY3lFU9mXiB6VUr4YEOGcepF4t3Cq5xaK0ZS32j7tFM3wPAakkSIBg30AjvhMss3uE6oFF5kDyvxg/h5Oey/kLtvGfYoVJcaZnxyWhNxhBRy9hpwAur58W2vmCKXB3EqDcpyh/2djlgSOnGTH7HBdoLrmW1nuYvLW3tLb3r2YmgnwSSmNMTT4rynGWlSdyWdJcBZjt2gq8vH5n/uErsTWDOEYeegxPF+mDKC7Uk5zGSxwURzhlACbSj9Q5jiOp+Ujg/uzAAVZSuCAJ1/9S8s2fddYJ5zBrcCieHoOSSXhRnFp7IaUWZcPGYbg5sAeP94ESwK7Kr4vS1bdmr89Npb72kruq42OnrS/WVnV2YGO/OINtDdnd3ojuUrkhN9o0Noyza/DvUsRrRs3P7x1fDG08Tv9whghpvGUtdkN5i1DEHc8hxl317FXIAxe3lyNW3nzNX7mir3Dnubd3eO3vXeWvNzs4lOyblll09pGekLHVqdqsdSphxSEgU6JCz0gKZcj9f82XC/rHoUw2tHpYpufMEmNunQHOTqw5qDT21dl3tjZ3qxB77jpKqVAyG+H/yG//NmywfyD1TPnO2JM+GssNPPna2Jc+ExkUpzWk+wuow9hLVyVlClq7A9R/EzhSw+QT0a/tkwtyzUEsfEZ9pxvP3mwPOkKVKBAaQEDQCEazxHncW6b2qBU/ORVUMZ9tvTzFF06GFQRLpx/bWVmsQv6MhaI1WwjjJRzgr1MZeoprPhG/tenwspvwMNOCTc2UR+9QCpao2jNamJyuAISoGGkTbrTK9nCEd9iCg6Cp5Me231rXJ0TO5+Y5y8axqmjJx8vW78Yh9HZKaF99K9Ce6E56Cf1cZ/yhs2oc6e9GR0QnUMEpjJA0Rz6HHuLkUT2fzlBO9H+Bs6cHOm2cXJrr/9CB7a69Jv5auSPUFDhggQYpDKBElZzz/MbKfQusZtUXqS5yU1RpffnfCrODn1VdG6dsZweP7IKkoVZl4yoecCz+d6kEUhIZ7OO8hcLI4Qn20LWXdKwP9il5gsiZy6N/UDCAoKnp6aai8ooU5ogb6MUUCsiJNKxRQ7ZIIw4cgQsQhSIY8BONvidNhmX6x+iUXtlE+saqZyCX3b89HeB0+dlfhkLlOz9qHYtbqQxMzmyOpQT6BkpaiYXgTRCCzyCLab1BnrFJmJuKNU60z/2i4wysbkKx6D/WEawSYemtLLV5pYhIt29hmFA3YMwo7XSHNr9f4BIdmSnE6SdfvBVK3wCoejZLS7n0jlAkjGEnDzdktBw/veERxWt0GexG2GUL27T6WFW1VcSVDW0Pc+EDFcIFobnJhbea0BGmzYS5QgiZy6HPSBvB+Y7MLNFM9P3u8x8ipBdtGxfmFLuUnFWiVZuWS/MbGlGtCQ8mdwKI0LX8Cs5IIw9wKI/CTDpIh+RmMP/KTmtgP7OU1+nszY9W87s1HPnz689mvlxWIWcJb0cVHqFVKktyAvolSXW3/RIXjPJKIZMZHRxPwpF9fsRe+MDMiCXYUJKNcSVTz1rfRXbNsaZ7X2O80mjdxiOSBQqPJ3Pvtk3O7h4fbP8yHSTyBHkn0J9oiz/yIkdhb2tWbEqdggR3rAVbGwM6yGQAvOXNI9xfJcUw9tvtD7Bjl8BNq4T1PZpGEXco6ny35WSYQwOQGKpJi7pCbLTvjFP2XKX2UxrnrQ1jtmbk5BdOITEitgh2z//LLMYDm8Y89+FnxaPgGzrbKg6PFjf2V912Z6BhqepoIVEqAnZ4Rzp4QUAcYWW9Vwu0h2o7glRSXIiq12D3X6iUTwXm05TFJ4T5Dc+0byxVjCv1Vs+2kDJxh1l8E4UvJQRC0VGCjQP2oURn1uD7woaerbqxvWK7eSIuq1H1SdNcQfZId9h/pO3KmIjRrdbzUH1LMqEePyCZ1bKch7X9yE/dCphxZiQxoKMsmoE2AQXGgAUfHyfVhsnHT1OMToX1C3z3nUKp5lzr2Ef/GdMWmKlrwm4i6SRcb/xF9Z+GH/jUwM4FikOoBNohSRSDNWXIUAndc4XDCeEtR0pZBXJsNxNTp4lCMZIRTFDZco0Zw5J0RXBcj4kK4Rje2HdXBYal8MVR/hS3MH/ZJ13/wuM++9v1nA5P0go1RxIQMu4GYyY9ndqZqjcCcoGzHKZnB9UfQtI2rHds3ALdqwRxj2iEo+iLOCA9x8vKElcnujW4LF9opKMZoM7+HNIq6K5/fW12MPP4Vl1h133J4fzRp6A1UtrcEoQekuy7m+kPmeDlnZIO9WDDM8sAEhsUIFst0WPGI1q8DUsJmWK6CVgN6XsuX2MdwAwYRR1nGNeAAUWbyXdkdp4JUZIy6tsJ+xxYT+fB6D9ZU5HpDPMYM2Ewwlj/PoK0w+MHu/ZUkq5j75n1fJfKhfAXcPwSkO0QUK9os6IBxFB/iTTqYEBgM0bWWKzAEYcdDEaHRAWOFBRNvyAZuxrFY8xgTim45MJa1ZXhrhy7mRSzxKGA6BbA/Rm8QXDTddpZqCZmv1aU3Str0ht2BI7Iqa0/PDFAXxxxGupCndg+3DJNvgXFfFmGEDg6ShDsDOcj0ia4oBHwNGtXMq/U+2PIdEEzFNKj+IsG+6w8CZz++x9VgUZ3bntiO3Q7afjhLaPcr6+dEJGC4Wyvd70R2smDNDgn6oYXvBr3A35E0tLxGojXXNFMM1kmPJ+UGuOqfUNbhoeyB4LPAuYKvwvCcMYqbGdMzAc4ujOe8qhlfh2oqiJlGECj2kh2ioseBxGvQ/Rg+O7o/y0SXdSBsW+y7ofGvxrMW8KYvyzhyXcMkYBQFSgPAm+wIwAbEwbsynGbYTeQKW0Zy5HHseXWlN0d0egzVwCCW8jNVHbhoQZQjnXdVnRpT1gn2f4jZbEW8Ey7fTIry8TzJXwe3om5FHjCnWKWvnfIQUgVVbrDg3NPIfMEHeZLzoI+xuWIpdogwvqvDtsG1dwQFAAyTZByBGiKc+lCHNeeHMcg647XGfIhaZlZu/AEMEqilhMuzZeQXANNbTCcjYrUFJYeG5vAfRvc10jA6BVO/g/ACDRmxvO8DoQLnyl4Qw3ciSahBibM6bm+tLMBI2fu6eQMWr8/ylnUTeSxI5c78AgFnI57lEfcbL9yNfzlaeoC3OL+FBwuYljuBIR+1nLLBgh0GgKBcWAxKKrz+juDOt4GdWoDP1xNwhoitHilDCoA9507azpm6L4BiyHvV1Kt0AaOppbKySUIrSJqyaaH2t+HlTW0lqDj8147hVmS8Qtoyu+UU1VhIsQle8p6Lql/Z/nfSmt1sNdpYXv6mAsbaUhprhalWjme6PyNp0hig2Sr+jeQydicElJakjOQV34bpMWr8Zk+9Of1NkB1CZKcLzYAumkIY82lxW62y52o5nbC13i1umznrofOS+x+KI5nRx3jZ2tmhSTfAM2gmzEh3NXOQTfZV0eBrxO1zI2DkQtThZLfEl13s8IGVY9d5/OY4AUG/Dv25k0bMNdN6M/t9n4SZDKVMQBha/LCdPVYRJa0ZijX6gzjlqVpbAtm/Km31yqY0bDzYPJUvSaSJko9wJla+CDXcdUF22b7RFl0IZHBZ0NGXsjLrnaW9s1cskR3y9oqexlAvyC3ds0nPxC87GxK9y1XroM/sAE2aoZYSNbDN6t29lBUsZc3BuiVyyga9ifGDDb1apuGF141sYLZDExYshixy2jqRk3ObTy1YGxpH/I3ZwqykFybs0goFTDpvlXJKHGTZpdRprrFFdJw34rcxThEj1BBt7MUb7oJmSsf2cWuG4sUSSwU0BNYkmTs8I+cF9EDOJqj3TFqwGsSKC6/ngbuwZ6NwdetNw4Y5hpm1mFVrHs7QDx0OdgLD2r1jNeDeROYaEZi1vFX80Ufojui16qa+RR+6n3xx4H7Ox2p6V5G7ypWTVKaqgyjhKTfMe8iaD54LDrn+nhUpp0qsTBGnL/JpoQQwoA+N+/tJpeb0O5Z229VyTQLZT2+3OmUp5j/fDcxsd9H2ru6vtmd9n7VdtT33HWHs78y+a7qn7J9rGHaK1kejMByJ7Jt74DyCIPfX3L/sgf+TQr8P2Mae3xU28WUp3Kq/0Q+nGWb2d+6EZEUsSftr3okD+OYBeAfmfDikEpxUKE7Fktik15jQa5pB/qbI8Ll0/rzQZWuaOduZTEpEoTqsVJl9ReD7kdSqglTttOXKBTkYsZ0EaVBWiyKsO02M70bQbeeNmIbYyYqr03FpyuVpCehIOxlSv3l3/Ll/eP4MpkSFX+CEQ3HXkpjUPoZ1Fkfsojp/Xl+cd1zMjhh+Yqk5gZncGhh1xSmkse5BsTfi4up/avW9Yzf4xS9fTl1EHYz3yc1clpuaVyL2Dw2KrMlIaDNYb2iyWX/EQD/HsbW87KgFd9rUyvACwKqsYuwvHWGcDx1CCCGk9h5P7e2Enao1NsV1dwd+YWu9JhMXURekiT+HKEOVn8WIRzxxcuXm9FsjUwDjVqfW1Nf4RNWW6Hjds5EKdd2W2z18hTVHE3OrLOKntfkB5vxY4LkZqjUGoIZ+siNYgEsKIVY1qBISggkJaz8c70Kt03gyJMHtzi8GXoCF3t/1d2bbdX3Vby3OUCKNYNV2iCAkBJ3Cj94oHnGw/c4PzBQpkXrZ2jQT93JFXWpYQgdodxUtzJC6OMQu/uIm80heJs+tjXGy/X0qE4VZuFmGiGNHR6M48VzePnNhGWVgrBNc/xGFD8QHRSk4WQq9b7Dzn7N3Nj5YMroUVquCBN7xGd2SClKqoiQzV1VV7F5ogmH4RrAWW9oF2bo5R5vAgo0yRF4Tl97WVlbRtqxA5LdqXpks9gpfQR1cHVDoirfhH7OxvGtuy45l8vYA6Q/WH9R86jPMf6xXuAtDXReU2TFKJxfLZ5gne3T8y+LpV9MlZo7jmxQYxsKwwgKDHmM463jm24XbzXnrgNMlJg5KjGzjmOj/YvuEi+unG6QDvWTD8645z8/KOXL/wcg84g/ut+OeAV5HslqTBOOE8kWPGnj3lhJTZxrcVzCdrZXUOswY1bT9TU5cbmWrxVrE9a9G+xPFO5UVludFOjkLA92//2dNk+E3yrUUzcXzXctLGqKtY7lZ+5rs43IaJnIa4qLfjN6ZfR9oyjQLj2lc39K0bHdfR6CF/OeMthLCJAvJ45fXDb160uvJm4yf5FmbVpvCkEpbJSXJSPYNb+0bZCQpSVsVhBetbhfthxAVI60mLSo72e6Je7RbYn1mLnMjZkkuR8YJDpV/aS8PDRWJYVtNco6fEqmSSJxqdpw5wTlzYkeNxEmCVClz/JJTFeWHFOUQovrWPTluMjne/W1jW1JMXtaBvKyYJHjaxicEEYSn2k8RhIQgfgP6oaKXmlvRFnouvGLl7y/crjsVTYohMT8pWEE8lk7LUFSk0uFjOwXcVC1SvrPnnqral08ZpKqZtPT8+FCyBMlWXjEWhp2IJUFn9Idofj31oYfnHwEWN/n8Oj48bSOqog3nsUipulXRJPLFFrcWf/9ucIEUz7mQQNGOP7FYHFaq2mfvCBoXtpX3fnjT5Xj0JJth7dsW0FVQfgggLoAQ1Vy/tO4kuCXpN1ovvTElnTcbP8tLn3+xOvILd6RaNuyRkWSk3HU6a1AHT/zZ8TfC3FZtRlBQdnf/J34BdeVd/3tMPgfMthzeS8lLHtC70uOdxtUr6Zi9pDC/QuY0IefOa6wDvgqQt8awQBw71gfDhW+rJSQpScGx4SheqdXe3mGlnIactxt7wkZAYYMTfDPgz21/SPLGPwie2sMy3tiLsIP0FmQkOBp9NppfSW29X38/4/5Wj/lQK/nKi+UXqVVUGH70j9iCf17/zc+lrjIkUfQBqe1nV2Se45Hv70eDsfAwSkob2fXu/7eQ3DQ4O0bqwpGywKDs3a6RtN9pcey3AHdU27bLEKVy2w76AVEiShk4qdSaZTAO2leHS0eaPvGaByqETvB4QJ6akfFg9s7SZ0JPSbCfryS40YTGjbbxCuQqkURJSyLGgk0yMzBrMokF74FBd1nt4cQwImsVx3Fo3Ryj0D2Qr0SSJYoYeWPtUfbLYxQSJFm5kHS3kahCkBWzwojhxPaLnaNvomGSEdZ6T92a/o4AGXAUc1ZP2s1DZG4W/sm9T8pT1mWkNdSlFzs9ro0DJlvgmrrgwoUFNO6c5tnepqdClBwV4HFMgqQpP8HDAdme3YYF1YVyl3haugRJUO4Jzo8wXRUhkyvG5ApFI/eS+BLX2rTQFNwGxCEpAViQvCf+rpwlhC38zmX6Q3HX1OduvtVZIMYGWLRN7wkNivAV+hDnKRdRdCXM/jAipEwvnpaQJKTqw0eA3B3lQ9lBOKtqnzeCD9/t8Aa13zfcOXtntCR4ATfMMww8m1Wo9MO2geONynGGddZvEE7GT+p28O0kN2LV1Iq6nKt/Y57kpGaM3pl1kaNralVEh1bzO+EG61YokVqJHt/ow9y0oNdDN8Q+PtQOvsxdDvRzE2aHRlnI9PwkSIwyxt6Db4TGuDpXZUm3OGGkLUE+nkEpkTHzH9QEOfBNtCKebT0D0k5n5npFB4REhK5zGmsRzlvkbYC8ibZW3wQ8lmnnJLOJufALsR+0j0iuRBGpZ7Sjb9jA2weH+jvERPQFXIm9MjyMuABB+/e49A5lhiFnuqULAkOrgqpiSLGk1mnlYbInINcrV+OHwi7gi3MEMZyYcHJjSfJo4L/G1TCyq0CnS2fZ6EiaDgwQEwqd8jJ55b9NWgUaW7YCt4OaL9QT5lNxOxxcfwn85pVn5jkVQr1q6vbZqbOATYiskUDjCwnr3LipjixS28FnD/U0ar0aeoT+VTdI34yC9s5vsiurkGOL2tlYM0/TlivTUrVLqvYxziBZNjydaXHu97ZP/ce9HcU/pBegoqtCNBO+xFCrVEVduXuaydpBkmeKzt3cd1ueXnDfhGY1OQOEm0XwbFeIFF0imhRoCctUokxZpki1LIEuBbqoa2RYt/z3O+1Hc+L3OysY7m3QTDQUMZVV1DChafAcbpV7q234wj3NXfJBvcrr7G1O2a/3un02bxemzAVjiczPl5x91qz1Fpphhr8zU4M8lJZO2auXyzBnpO8zActr7pIJK4dgPjh48FF//99J2WnD9fUhxd07Ze+s401NrDVjst3ZTLPaRKq3jvNxHlEL1wFDt+J7FYrK3kpbV9z78YEDpRtcXtGX9RjU40RfuGDLNba/7Jy3BiQZ/e8eqRc1cWueRsBhCpiACg5FqzUoUEP+48LIyE1WB5mTwImnIOgh142r60J9UkNVZyHEMFOhvjesX6UjLkKniuYB3id4rUrq6/eaOXt7Jn/m9tntbsncwHnB2coc6N8oMd3r5QLWLN8yM8VC7Bi5nGUQSKbuujsfYDoPWnx+BFf54w7hnMo9MuXSweSglCT/hiK81vHlUkvhdW3gOaZEOlZv6OrY11DYvc/BG+7tgpY0CoMcgiQ+CYND/2nJktylxrrBFNNpN5BYAXa7vcjFIzjCM9KtmWNlwrTkBIvYPCMmj9XsBhFWKm/PQBdL5wlq1j1K9uCKVPeMTPmX3byw4aUDvHqXu6rOWWGLLEfuDzTeZEdbwJL/IIrDtI1ZIC9Ff7ylc1WlkJKQmJBIEVb2h1nDcCP4OzDYmm/8ZcjIpF+j5nhX0fegcCea6j4aTtwqzDTOFPS6tK3bbQ7a2P7N2dafnJjwFk/4TXlLe+NxEd7TkUqbyrrQDm3ltLxRvQ9CpN5LhNqkYzlCdasx6wl7jizrVIVVA3TJHxqVzZOB4dEjbpwXrTc8wXMC5jElHNfKNULWeUj4OHOsiKU0QwE7bCTrnh6/lQUQjCAB9cUEU7GtusHmegL1uGDjtxnC47AsRK0JAYM1woKV3Fe2O+g5oCjJsjdk54fiFQcgMMqd1FZiBpRsNimxl5BwcnYZUSY0sGsQfstkD96GaTLpmx/jZffntgQPVPHp8QuWdhy+ma6yRM+IkpLPr3dTFrAKTCe9xAXlRQuEA+89QO0PCCt3Sfnw45Fw5XO8gHaUySUlQWgWBGkyaMeXpicizAtmPXVI16NKjXO4okqX+oZ2R8sFNbL8vDSPSRmSoZyxNr/Jt3K1sR4d5XOvW5iP8wROgX4DitV321qtai7MVhRJc+DJ7hKxZUDWCpTF6Izaio9D0kEf76wZUdOkD5c0PVv+l+ig4iVVY8tag66+Hux7x7iJaX1vCXhly2yMgPiV/nOeyMh7RR/q8f5+BMq3p8xIfirHb6qNc3T664R1zQm1qIeHwgShe+ybl0pI6eXxGRoa/E8ADE3IszHYXfGGaXGwfEp9d0tIQZxRNYamGiyoKMr0bFbn7MKxKjCzzLZn3eOuY0xh+MCLWRlgFlOR/ys67F2ry8Z0K+qX5mQ1KhfEy2vjQvdQRCG2ZULNhLm3mwSRK2sJye7pnprIFbp0LVNb9qyVxZgZbxgmxZjWdEn/g79yh4rIuiAcKCaKiovlG+VZXEyli1MMooxLCGI5z9BmDdyonb/q0g2yL1uVcL0mPO6wtZGmnr5upjdDER398YJfrpNt0sq24M0mu62/q/C1VGjx5nol3MAb2voCEL5Bo5W0pSdOKy6NfhEYbsoAusBFK/Wf0+ftz/uzt5gexHlJ4pwNtBrk7NkIbbpNNazlR0UfrfEltcPXdNM19Z3QG+1VDq+PcJq4RrkQzFbiRCLf/7Li3AUK2/64wGdtxVLCjnHSU7nkHZkgUfYbGTCaRMyAo5Akoy+kCxlJZ9CUba97U+gyHZvl1dqB20XKoG6pXYwdvanXGMauIsvM74MaBGzZzjTaG9VYp8uNaoT3CLXQdtR1vyUYBmW+aUzR8Cq+iW4Hx+Z1LSQY/GNrF4woNfc99rTKvVbnkddflR45ro6Udjfwg04Rr4Xj0Sp9wGts8IadtWMLiK40vLeFErCoJ8Pk0lPRQkBPEhDovoxMoZl2RiyDbaVMcjvOqyYy0x3I5AumEsIsMGitpuE1jEMjwSy2uSAAhok45nXcvW3fXPf2agavrx+wpZww44JjdWBu3JEUcKkTS0tLU9kTazOo6chy2X40Q/JFkR9ra15N0tdf7W2r1theXPLJXpqMGbeNjf9JLIVcxiEiBJMs2+ULVgerVtLb55FGqjWRqf6A8DoCe9g2R/UQ4Wc3F6s1ABk46051QC1CCP4qR6azFKZu7WYybwkmO3iztDAldrYjhZZ1K+Q56bHNHg8KprbSGtO8fiHRHD8gPNxiF2Z1soJCW+/Re+eA4Z5Rocc6b/msh/lLwcwY/tvX2ITeGWhdJkCR6ThhxwDa02aYsDAgmiAhM8BubqmV1nTZ410hGdB1OA/V4w9/wT/VaRFdrRHR4Gy/dalaOwbr6FiPq60ppaUCUuwBrQEWi44ulUsqTrUNXl/Ers/kK+wiCa5zuyNy14xXmJLOom5OHihpK3EZrb0lPvCGBXCWBTObXopBnmUs7wORol6HpGjXGES85u6JCmql6I5npkyg9yE1aPQh5KKBxVWzBe+BzXA5V+qY10Ws3JXXdXInDnVbB2mxnU67PP3E3uTMYHlm8t69SVNH0103AXiEfaPmrGVfmHekaMnXriIuH2O4gGYScjFMvFaopmiQbaSis869NM2SfjNzAIe5Yj8zbrUbZpfUPln2cT0v7fEUZFu4nNj52kGWKYtLs/uIUKnwlYUEYgkdtRDcVZZuNnNPoB/oB8s49ufhyol7rvXvm6a/uHULNRjsGon192VJnFbsWJspwDm5TortvlEOp45LolcunQY0OO1OukvDa2V2WapdWIH6W24k5sYIforqkQRQtFdlt6nB1ISrNeHcw03xwsfV4TVspjFvgu25abMnBX09inzTFjmORpE03ySgaDZPr+FIO7NCS5aiLnEQ8tPpyfy2ydFMp+jLHBg4ZdKNwDLpW0m+KSHtXHLw8yofZf0irr2rWVTqHU9mrr6E3MEUMjROCmZxWwwVpldZ7in69X+hdDGyxK6nG6aCCads1XxjqjjxrUWCQLi6fiIoI9gudemleX4ysKpGNMqaJX0QoITq5S1YAFRZjU/nVqu/dUA5OGYrC5l7pyfXVNmQmDSNtoFuIOG+pmRLjNtpdbKTYdvpaje3eVhj/XRJnM9AogThFAculgSKx8kMfGqBKWd2tljfI20lux3NIOVwBwxruoXrKzO091r2RDZ18w11++m6PPlmLUiaoLrhBdbelJwORt3mxDtrEVoJz9b95FGiwbhRk1fMVxtU7bUSU0arutCiJ9ovXn1oxlXZrJ8cmDAHX1oBroMYoQUkmvMTGrUdQ0+qGlwPCkSXcf5gQHGxuCjQ37+dBuDito+AB4d0v7HnSAJA22eBAqzR8ZBQ582+omPYo09Ewb5N2bakTznpPvPTzeklS6smltUUz7WrER5/alM673nkc166/27sQH4Yo0CspXnwqW32ZZp8rfz5T2jW5yyx3qLiBnbjH9sYr/GFee98dp/hXPSZaH4Jf9zZ5VvWRfTxS6mzbY76UEv5o2bcH1kurkMto8LOaJ/tVfNW5JTXm4eeIdVSbRkizh4dTfc2V07yzbApB/U6rLR/rF4oaLwz+3YwMG2tW+zmaZCwjr3ucpJ/qdgdZmLK1EZLG4KQEDxD9tYOFRx38w3paxzS19dbnZpjEpAhfX8ju1UHtLDpML9GBti6QEXN5be8fL6x3wIokWbtfT03eFq7WQAQJ+DzmhtPmHuFhZfjbC/zTW8RvHK96Qbivs7J4O+rsTDchi3+M5APpvE95hfXZj+52Oh8aWYkvItyIzGGqmf4cxZTKv0Ma9s0Xfau6E+bww4FbZKxR/D0fgKttMJKRrq3Oj6DuIZu167JoxYMdpXoOtLCCL3gD4K92QeDoIJwCfdnwooubX7zxZoeal08Jo/3ReJptZouD271DvF+L/f8V97lF1D7P3UHZQdltNWW5LZptHsxx7/4W2uzNk5eG7+gUZmVrVhc5bZm4doOehLJTokUSbCLRDoTV9z3cCzMxiysZtm2pvaOfeDeMS1OENTvCGOGVG550Gnt4WJmbGLmvMzHh2diygP3DuHIrjEwNEYtCah/EEqgaXIt+fNf+AMPES5Fb0cBvbNfBjE6if+1+B7Pi5xeOF3YacWHDvfc2cMl0e6mTSsOB9PyB4eSyQ5B/GIbODQQkh3g7cvYJ/HPFUbMV0gQsTKQX8ln8UJTTFL8uCzdzQznRAaIt4PT5zUn+FZUO2b2ZDeOasWfDfn3u3uSHcItHyCQbLSMXybuuMMP0+FZx+dnpMuAqMTJpEl+VDe701tt0aGF2TLeA7WjtENECCFYa8I0VCt+dGp84yw8O9WamjSTOMO3gvmENorxPC9euRY6yMu0uSC7L0y68+kdwIAL75Mc3Xt8XV6HamRXowHeYRk2jnrvrrl7gJazSDnO03JoaxMvrf086FW2s+zIP5p8lE/r3H/gR0Q/YY/ZbAqJua0x/sjNcjrYfeqjFj9v00oLiI5I9e/52K7Rx4sHrvX0PKe4Xiulc2IBOHYq6AwR1UrgboNRSu9f1DGNDkuJDAmLDg95Q4+H3t5nfBfbSFsXOB0ktgU9qvGUKfPqolNoaxwbKKqtPsn5Il4OStxebNgAvX0KhwhuD0icCdcGjHCbx1bEGQaXt1dtWeU5dKbM3tEil0xyjQajZEUMiZbl/hliHp1aLbUwof5y09jPdM3wt65/6qqwYXW/m0EtFXbLK6b+WYSh8dzRIP9jgNMMNVbTyak0xP9yy+B5Ymo91DinxcD5NpzjjITxTHsrntsWtWYzqOsAg4H62DnV4hQKdcsIYb7SF4xtZ06LpNzvZKJDTQvoaBzRqo1p3KimNY6g9cbvayHum4tBh9xD3135c37PtbsHaSNoObsyJ+dv238mogcd3vfEFzaVntRdZTVmoxK1Pbb7mbf7Zs+EIRUZFV5KRi+58shqo6pEzUQszgIXO6FJHDgTsHJEXxJSLJr/bmfCd32K/kz59PzhceAq7O6ZV7oWt9+ZXdtIvzValZ16CZHXRAqkmH0puKvyOOvGp8znzd+3zXy+LfP54/ezbZ9doU3hvgHMVEzgo+Uhbsv9Y76y9cyCq/Gypl1Zi7Tw2YWjakPfrfUwO5yhwSFH8fkGkvIQZ+8lHvZRLuX8ee09qBPOlio24xftLRFFfEtj5qDM2CwRiw1LujwDwcK7j1t+TKZbtCnd/2D2EcY2HJH7VejatAlcwn282ANnrSDK7R8uJYhs6mZ8+/ESesPwPzNH9Zc6pKRkPygYHPr/qgj35tJVY3qX72x3H3uBgIb4DF0JIh+U+4qRMkfPsVy4VHxQJzZ1uM5tP9il6DaSftyspPdCF+kILb2iwp5hNiluDUkbg6AmbQw81bKGrvuqmfqVZ9V36gCb4D7bcxg/7d0t/OHqsoeqhhONEoHnZn+w/CnV45FdzfCEaHtzH6RXYWx7UEpqU2pqYPS9n+LA1Eqh+Oe9yQt256m0N3WBRjU0ERxi92D5EtusQZLANcFRq7R2K1i3we2lua+3pr5smt6qzoWg31Go1ix9sf695T1wXW2hvp6nHm97uWZcPXYtFQKvNWfT/Qf9Pp0/uD8KzxCvyNWaHBivkHli6kx7TooUNJ6jAb3NHz+9271JbyXJS9xETH+hiSz1/2aw0+1EaWiUaODwGEK3jgPjbfF+GNgcFpRraHCjm+F2fEsPP3oAeSeumpTo8RoESBhzuqDT9jos/fTUWhAQKzJn92bMp7EpPra4aQGidw/B8P3lAbrfkUS6uOraSK78wQyzvHmhKIo0/CvDznB6oPaSd7fDEnSHjLQH8Qfd4KUTak4wewdFwtVr+DjWdY/2/Y13fMX53XFfbCePyBsDckv4k6znC+YH8XP5x8GpJmtlOsPHqMWn/MrCfLzfkvwbCq9hlxKOXlYODTo3aTjLp52CJadcqE4gCs4B1IMvNnQ5VZW6Nm3MtsPXHsf48LXpBYNDh53DU0L9vf1Dw1w9Exd9+EhQ0Z8vn8S13BZI3EfkF+dkXQRMDl11LqR68F9QkG8fOGWUu6HiNP0JOV5/PjHS+EtudORV0/qs2u9bfylY+es4Qe3Pbb8Ax2xd0zplGSqi6ZGJ1dCx9MoxfWXM2kdnRzvVwylpbe6Vaf/bkv4x55MuzCgqiN3FCoTm+3jceI7tde1bIw6xdBO7WUKnd/iefn99up8efP/iCOgX7273TuZG/6+MiFM9BA7KI/aOHNStm+jxGS3kIju/9Xkz+dzAX7f4K3ZDsUdYrGGV/cg3MGbiuIudeS+ohzbF8J94qTHchdJnY1n2rcl0GMYZZglHWMbDKPchyn4Ishzm8Qy4Ej93JHoIMbJp/RtrWsrQazaUVegYnvSEGa49PZDR7Wh2WXVlOrauQ4xCp03s5JmCJyLKIxo1k7SHxDHH3jl0Ls4MxdAhFw7McomXU7pi3HOj1sZqOkZ4YHcn/jDOowtZxd5WvexvYXQz9ItX5n4Y99DNgZepJjR4DKBE1mPl5XL3+vNofbxU0fvNbegCe9JSYYCZInW8MqI2gHaawo/Ey/WMWWbsFMmUsII+zZOTY/eP1xPDzIqKkS8FZnhD+QCOLy7m2OzC1IXa8bH+BdN3YWxKFs491wQz2eUQjg+Px3ciIsYuXLUotgbnYQEM8uzIJzdMPVmN5PjV+MJ4WEwhYBzm7j+NLgV88ID80eD8VhZbEB0rurkTy9XkTWxfwLuqgUKkU3h89aWAm58Zw2+30+0XbHZphcx9DAsNYNXyPfQaJ3WQIrY1NGcM0zNuW0z3V16djbdEc4CnASwaCagAjyzGZvZjE4WygJueKDalAl9dQfnAYVdALRg3EpQafAeAXHLw3tWZBngG1TldL9yXbLWb5nVLYvfH+bFK6kYH2O7ZQlWM9l4B2yjr15nVrDpiFGB72pdmFeJIj+x8+ZmYuduFmk687hyuMZbb/NSefX3hx+rgmpynG4XOUJPqs555riGcGUpXM/e26oBVD/OgYTwtNo/4PBZ6sxy8ldwav06yYo2tsYc5/91UuFfZjE9nhC/PVoY3vfiPfcYfP3lMlnkMZsyxKY9u1bRwHXdj91fsfrCi6AJcoGxrszFGSnW+rW/cdP5RDK7l5UrsmW+XKWTOLY4PGDPsxp0zwcyvbDfZ1lexxvmMStpyWb4So7laVj8uZopOtDtWUzHbQ5neIvoGVx2py7fTD00UE8lRBaUQIhI8hMIN/vBzd4mXXd6trjQyZhaxEopPRolM3obLX8fSOBDQt8XQBhhAEOAE3cq6yICI4glaNAR3dQA/6MS/Qp0hdELnKMdpnYcwpeoC9GkDFlY/1MXMZj7zS9Bn7wDrxEwHwIMAFEFzQlFQnitao9eKwWinYn3tsmqhTcGKI5jyoFO9SwmE07f/IRLMFhSsTDmFSgXy5KvGYSWbNQ5njpy44MiiwBEt04WKGOeQOD9UpkYxuVpVimTaKRAGFXeLcUJ61YjygJy1970cAvBb4oxlW3O+iNPe6Mz1SUUmR1KQV1ZTLK+tKspUZP5Udc1cd9UvkToOcO6FfVSumD2hYpmyFYFzb6iUF9t/XLkPg8U2AK5TpoRACYVcZUoTEgG5TCoGSwtUev7FRakseNlFmUfbZbjAVp0ZdXKDBVZ9M84Eah28KgWhb13AVb4sLuC6u0oEJYo3lM6qvpE6+auYI9+9BCtJtFmQtYygLreooNpZ8F3M9rnmZ7kkX5TjtDkRTiNcdtn5HE4EHNe5PiTicEypheZTXrVs13it8gQ8VH6JTEXk0zS3ZYoVyLqSmlv/c+zJhTMvPn/Z2AdjYE7fO15SEsdp0p+e/LLq7IrV7nOBxwVvfB0vBbmC4oIsZ4Fbvwg9XZy9fEhZee7ZcEnG2+OIyR9IlE9ncYhV7xBdl9ws/6je5PMW2OJqnpfufjufSLATGrALjZIoONRgZ8yuVs6bQw/XGYKUhk0R/oQyWjMN+CgGat0ffL15pXidd3aZoKYogkSzWFAF1kwezCqRv6t6OYQ9dKf0f2vOfpH3bSCoYll2tK3s74c9bL0Xllj5f+RO27S7o9Uaf1rmhAcGffHZV1uMOOu0UVmydcpxntwZ51x2wUWXvJTrqium7ZLnvVVuuOa6fK+8oVKoQJESxUptUqZCuUpValSrVWdWvQYKSgs1mrDZHxZp0uy1t4qYNVXTDTP/+j/LnQPptfDZfofN4fLyX//i0wbSDEsW+Z50reIO7EQweyDluGuZf/uNd5rRaHWsWfPOFkY0ZjcLTy9vPvD8+NMO7vITT/nk2ztYPPueeU4pXyudZfv7mCe/W/5x1z33PXLbwwoUKlKsRKky5Zzby9aqU0+hgXd7u4v8wVBI6IA8nkB7FyxTqDQ6gymEE+jPR48vEIrEGppa2jq6evoGhkbGJqZm5haWVtY27bHXOI2T9lE7pcVxSw2ZcsSkQ23tWtHewdHJua4u9ej2znar9flLh7XW2f8INAaLw+sNRhPjV0VurxfCbLHa7A4QO11uj9fndy9C+rTMcSgxnUDSOJm3kSjesDEUCaiTMimJ5dPOQLTSxLNKH/AsGUzPFSf8DSY7ESONFHWSGGxCgYnYyCOFA2J4rdA6SfU/oWrXVNT6xGpaVsmITn9mVL/TiZmyAYzBTCMCLidg2AA0mhtLy5aD18yxF+i0QfP9tO6keQ13EyPejLrXgThsZGglthoiYnjwhcRQhYVPJ2mO9dH0GKk+Cry9nGPok2M3Y50DdSqRpZXaaomo+qK6NkR45axv58+bvk948xzovejbMjF9nYa2JiOyW7ERsgcr3r8bjTGHrXZ8Elv3kb1RWZFYJEcWdr06qy2dFrcDd17DT51094mqZxeMIJFEZzQCIlJkjBjh/ZzOyJsiuuvI8uA8jT1uu5EJj2L32vWoXbYRBSJb8YxSRUXgpbUttV5vtA/NLaObNCayzZYoUYQEVc3ucOqGy+3Jb8kiJKhqdodTN1xuT353pg0AAAAAAEiSJEmSJM8a028n6ji1WUdIOhOyJ6wdbU+c5R04PdVbSxQ+WkbzdI9oSyg9rsU4FGHw2K51ODdidXFTJTirDt9HylcOacfycrUL8GEBfPV+PpB86P+2t2QuYlWXkwwdGYL9+oe4Gva+yZym/vQsrH6uUKkmnkeErTU5/aSeZ7amz3fnZKC0r8QWxD/M4b/EIbq1nXWFlxMpFNQPDMtKt4kV/PWKp0Wm4/YABq5iXLATFhZ5CKhSJFWIHiXqBxEksSKJPSFCFBgLgTwgREgEPQoC0GOCRBAEPV7YpJ8bYWHRKgIA) format('woff2');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<style>
  .block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #00f;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .block-inner {
    background: #f00;
    font-family: 'Merel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 0.8; /*Adjust this*/
    padding-bottom: 0.45em; /*Adjust this*/
  }
</style>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-inner">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Found a good article - https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Answer (score 1):

You could build something similar with this. You should just add a `span` tag to your HTML code.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Merel';
  src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff2');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}

.block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #00f;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .block-inner {
    background: #f00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  span {
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Merel', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-inner">
    <span>text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```